# Errors in Visual Studio, sorting 3 numbers entered, and displaying them in increasing size

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program to input numbers from three text boxes and then display them in increasing numerical size.

What is the work around?

[image]

[image]

I have tried 2 methods.

First method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    num3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

    if ((num1 < num2) && (num1 < num3) && (num2 < num3))
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num1 + num2 + num3;
    }
    else ((num2 < num1) && (num2 < num3) && (num1 < num3))
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num2 + num1 + num3;
    }
    else ((num3 < num1) && (num3 < num2) && (num1 < num2))
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num3 + num1 + num2;
    }
    else (num3 < num2) && (num3 < num1) && (num2 < num1)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num3 + num2 + num1;
    }
    else (num2 < num3) && (num2 < num1) && (num3 < num1)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num2 + num3 + num1;
    }
    else (num1 < num3) && (num1 < num2) && (num3 < num2)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num1 + num3 + num2;
    }
}
```

The 2nd method I tried has errors as well...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    num3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

    if (num1 > num2 && num2 > num3)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num1 + num2 + num3;
    }
    else (num2 > num1 && num1 > num3)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num2 + num1 + num3;
    }
    else (num3 > num1 && num1 > num2)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num3 + num1 + num2;
    }
    else (num3 > num2 && num2 > num1)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num3 + num2 + num1;
    }
    else (num2 > num3 && num3 > num1)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num2 + num3 + num1;
    }
    else (num1 > num3 && num3 > num2)
    {
        label1.Text = "" + num1 + num3 + num2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace all your `else` with `else if`

Comment: Those are syntax errors that point precisely where the problem is. Just double click on them and fix what's missing. Hint - there's no `else` with a condition.

Comment: `label1.Text = string.Join("", new[] { num1, num2, num3 }.OrderBy(n => n));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `if..else` code with following code which will sort data in list and display in label.

```
int num1, num2, num3;
num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
num3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

var list = new List<int>() { num1, num2, num3 };
list.Sort();

label1.Text = string.Join(" ", list);
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `list.OrderBy()`, and not `list.Sort()`?

Comment: @mabako : Yeah. we need to use Sort for inplace sorting. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: You event dont need to parse them to int : 
`var list = new List<string>() { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text }; list.Sort();`

Comment: @greyxit - wrong, `textBox1.Text` is a `string` you wont be able to add a `string` to `List<int>` - as you can see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/P5qd9H - okay, you changed the type to `List<string>` which is a bad idea - since the sorting wont be natural as you can see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xQsaHa - Output is 1, 10, 2 and not 1, 2, 10

Comment: The `List<int>` was a typo, but you're right for the sorting.